# This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpwebrequest

I am getting error on below code.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
response.Cookies = webRequest.CookieContainer.GetCookies(webRequest.RequestUri); //Error here
string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
responseReader.Close();
```

> Error : System.InvalidOperationException: This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: The cookies should already be part of the returned response.

Comment: I will need to maintain a cookies for all request as well I have remove the cookies but still getting same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[HttpWebResponse.Cookies Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_HttpWebResponse_Cookies) should already contain the cookies associated with the response.

You should also avoid calling `GetResponse` multiple times.

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
    var responseCookies = response.Cookies;
    string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    //...
}
```

You can reuse the cookie container for subsequent requests as they would have been added by the response

Comment: Yep. It's the second call to `GetResponse` that is getting you.

Comment: Now, I am using the GetResponse only one time then it's working fine.